# How to find the condition of k in a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

$3kx+9y = 1$

$x+3ky = 3$

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 3k & 9 |1 \\ 1 & 3 |3\end{bmatrix}$

and the answer is:

when $k \not =$ -1 or 1

$\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{3k-27}{9k^2-9} \\ \frac{9k-1}{9k^2-9}\end{bmatrix} $

another question with 3 k's

$3kx+3ky = 5$

$12x+3ky = 1$

$\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{12k}{9k^2-36} \\ \frac{3k-60}{9k^2-36}\end{bmatrix} $

how do they got the answer? I really need help. I don't even know what's the first step.

Comment: Check out this scrolling down till "Applications - Explicit formulas for small systems": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule

Comment: Thank You!. Solve it perfectly